# Breadcrumb floating to right but still blocks other content to squeeze inline

Tags: css, reactjs, material-ui

Inside `Breadcrumbs`, I have `home/profile`

The following is the ideal layout where `Breadcrumbs` are floated to the right but `Other contents` are not floated to the left.

`Ver1`

```js
--------------------
        home/profile
--------------------
Other contents here..
```

Right now, if I add css `float:right` to `Breadcrumbs`, all contents are squeezed into one line. How to avoid this happen and achieve `Ver1`

`Ver2`

```js
-------------------------------------
Other contents here...   home/profile
-------------------------------------
```

I'm also using react material-ui

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add a clearfix div after Breadcrumbs to fix the float.

```js
<Breadcrumbs/>
<div className='clearfix'></div>
```

then in css

```css
.clearfix:after {
    clear: both;
    content: ".";
    display: block;
    height: 0;
    visibility: hidden;
}
.clearfix {
    display: block;
}
```

Comment: Just checking `.clearfix {
    display: inline-block;
}
.clearfix {
    display: block;
}` are right??

Comment: sorry only .clearfix { display: block } should be needed. edited